# Windows move to external monitor when re-opening lid

Tags: 12.10, laptop, cinnamon, lid, dualhead

I'm using Cinnamon (on 12.10) on a laptop (Compaq 6710b business model) with an external monitor. Both screens run at 1680 x 1050, the external monitor is located on the right.

During normal operation everything works fine; windows open in whatever monitor my mouse pointer is when they open and I can freely drag them to the other monitor.

When I close the lid of my laptop both displays shut down as expected. When I open the lid, however, the lock window opens on the external monitor and any windows that were open on the laptop screen have moved to the external monitor as well.

Nothing happens between closing the lid and opening it; no suspend, powerdown, hibernate or anything, monitor stays attached; even mouse is untouched (pointer on laptop screen).

Is there any way to fix it so my windows stay on whatever monitor I left them before closing the lid? Alternative solutions are welcome.

Addendum; if the laptop suspends while the lid is closed and it's brought up again, the windows do stay correct. This problem seems to happen when the lid is opened while still running instead of when closing the lid.

Comment: This is rather a tricky issue having a Cinnamon DE and all. I wonder if this is the case running Gnome or KDE or some other DE? Hummmm.... since this is a setting rather than a distribution problem I would have to say you or we or us need to have the boys over at LinuxMint look into this, since Clem (the developer) of Cinnamon is the one to ask, and I am a member of the LinuxMint community I would be happy to further this question there for you, however this question will become "off topic" as it is not a Ubuntu problem as I see it. With your permission, may I proceed to ask this question in t

Comment: Please, by all means. I did run Unity and Gnome3 for a short while (a few days both), and neither had this issue. Cinnamon is 100% consistent in this; happens every single time.

Comment: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=118915 POSTED

Answer (score 1):

This exact same thing is happening to me on Ubuntu 12.10, every time I close my laptop.

One work around is to `apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`, run `ccsm` from the command line, enable `Window Management -> Put` and configure a keyboard shortcut for `put_next_output_key`. That way as soon as you open your laptop you can move the window back to its original position.

This will also re-size the window from a large screen to a smaller screen which avoids another bug in Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10 of not being able to drag and snap a window of a larger height to a monitor that is a smaller height

Comment: I've had this for years, the shortcut. Its still bloody annoying having to do this every single time :!